# Need help retrieving data from a text file in python

Tags: python

I need help writing a code to retrieve some values from a text file (tfile.txt) and assembling the value in each line to the respective variable on the array st=[h,c,r,b,f,w,s] or even just assembling it to h,c,r,b,f,w,s variables (don't need to be in an array).
Thanks in advance.

Edit: problem solved, but now I can't use the variable st (sum of all the other int variables on the text file) on my other code, because it is a variable inside a class function

```
    class File():
      def get_st(self):
      f = open("st.txt", "r")
      a = f.read()
      b = a.split('\n')
      h=int(b[0])
      c=int(b[1])
      a=int(b[2])
      f=int(b[3])
      r=int(b[4])
      w=float(b[5])
      status=b[6]
      st=(h+c+a+f+r)/5
```

and I want to use it on the following code:

```
  u=Unim()

  while st >=140:
  u.nim3()

  while st >=60 and st < 140:
  u.nim1()

  while st <=79:
  u.nim2()
```

I also want other classes to be able to overwrite these values:

```
   def existing(self):
    for i in range(60):
      count+=1
    if count is 60:
        h-=1
        r-=1
        c-=1
        w-=0.01
        a-=1
        f-=1
    else:
        Existence.existing()
```

Comment: Why do you need them to be in variables? Why not just an array with all the data? I realize that you said "don't need to be in an array"...but why?

Comment: @hqkhan I want to use these values to find the value of st and use it in another function outside its class.

Comment: Since you're reading the file and you know how it's structured, you can store the items in a `list` of lists. Your approach of storing items from a line into variables is most certainly not the best way to go about this. If you want further help, post a snippet of your file here so someone here can replicate the problem and provide you with a more reasonable solution. I see your edit and you don't need to create a `class` for this issue.

Comment: @hqkhan how can I do this?...Sorry if the question sounds a bit dumb, but I'm kinda new with python and I'm not really good with getting and overwriting values in a text file.

Comment: I don't mind helping. But I need to know what your data looks like, what your desired output is. This is why your question was downvoted -- there isn't enough information for anyone to help you properly. From the looks of it however, your problem should be simple to solve unless I am mistaken. The edit you made, what is `Existence`? Why are there 3 `while` loops? I'd highly suggest you go through a programming tutorial that goes over fundamentals for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the the following is similar to what is found in your text file:

> Hello  Hi Hallo Hola

This should do something along the lines of what you are looking for

```
f = open("textfile.txt", "r")

a = f.read()
b = a.split(' ')# separates by space, but you can do lines by using '\n'

print(b)
```

b is an array that contains the following

```
['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hallo', 'Hola']
```

You can then just insert the values from b into your variables

```
c = b[0]
```

Comment: `code` def get_st(self):
            m = open("st.txt")
            config_dict = {}
            for lines in m:
                items = lines.split('\n', 1)
                config_dict[items[0]] = eval(items[1]) `code`

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("tfile.txt", "r")

filedata = file.read() #read the file into filedata 

print(filedata) #if you want to output the data from your file also 

output = filedata.split(' ') #and then you can split it, into a list, on space

print(output) #then you can print the resulting output
```

Comment: And why would you assume the file consist of just one row?

Comment: I'll add "filedata.split('\n')" can be used if you wish to split per line.